# Creating a setter method that takes extra arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, setter, indexer

I'm trying to write a method that acts as a setter and takes some extra arguments besides the assigned value. Silly example:

```
class WordGenerator
  def []=(letter, position, allowed)
    puts "#{letter}#{allowed ? ' now' : ' no longer'} allowed at #{position}"
  end

  def allow=(letter, position, allowed)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Writing it as an indexer works and I can call it like this:

```
gen = WordGenerator.new

gen['a', 1] = true
# or explicitly:
gen.[]=('a', 1, true)
```

But when I try any of the following, the interpreter complains:

```
gen.allow('a', 1) = false # syntax error
gen.allow=('a', 1, false) # syntax error
```

Why won't this work, am I missing the obvious?

Comment: related / duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280623/setter-method-assignment-with-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It doesn't work because the parser doesn't allow it. An equals sign is allowed in expressions of the form `identifier = expression`, `expression.identifier = expression` (where identifier is `\w+`), `expression[arguments] = expression` and `expression.[]= arguments` and as part of a string or symbol or character literal (`?=`). That's it.

`gen.send(:allow=, 'a', 1, false)` would work, but at that point you could as well just give the method a name that doesn't include a `=`.

Comment: Thanks. Funny thing is it allows stuff like 'def seed=(value) end; gen.seed=(1)'. I would have expected 'seed=' to be the identifier, but (if I understood your rules correctly) it goes like: [gen/expr].[seed/identifier]=[(1)/expr]. This would explain why it fails with more than one argument -- (a) is an expression, however (a, b) is not!
Assuming this holds, how does 'gen.[]=('a', 1, true)' work?

Comment: `.[]=` is another special case which I forgot in my list above (along with `expression[comma_seperated_expressions] = expression`, which of course also works).

Answer (score 8):

I have come across this and decided to pass my arguments as an array or hash.

E.g.:

```
def allow=(arguments)
  puts arguments[:letter]
  puts arguments[:position]
  puts arguments[:allowed]
end

object.allow={:letter=>'A',:position=>3,:allowed=>true}
```