# Setter method (assignment) with multiple arguments

Tags: ruby

I have a custom class and want to be able to override the assignment operator.
Here is an example:

```
class MyArray < Array
  attr_accessor :direction
  def initialize
    @direction = :forward
  end
end
class History
  def initialize
    @strategy = MyArray.new
  end
  def strategy=(strategy, direction = :forward)
    @strategy << strategy
    @strategy.direction = direction
  end
end
```

This currently doesn't work as intended. upon using

```
h = History.new
h.strategy = :mystrategy, :backward
```

`[:mystrategy, :backward]` gets assigned to the strategy variable and the direction variable remains `:forward`.
The important part is that I want to be able to assign a standard value to the direction parameter.

Any clues to make this work are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Due to the syntax sugar of methods whose names end in`=`, the only way that you can actually pass multiple parameters to the method is to bypass the syntax sugar and use `send`…

```
h.send(:strategy=, :mystrategy, :backward )
```

…in which case you might as well just use a normal method with better names:

```
h.set_strategy :mystrategy, :backward
```

However, you *could* rewrite your method to automatically un-array the values if you knew that an array is never legal for the parameter:

```
def strategy=( value )
  if value.is_a?( Array )
    @strategy << value.first
    @strategy.direction = value.last
  else
    @strategy = value
  end
end
```

This seems like a gross hack to me, however. I would use a non-assigment method name with multiple arguments if you need them.

---

An alternative suggestion: if the only directions are `:forward` and `:backward` what about:

```
def forward_strategy=( name )
  @strategy << name
  @strategy.direction = :forward
end

def reverse_strategy=( name )
  @strategy << name
  @strategy.direction = :backward
end
```

Comment: Edited to add another suggestion for alternative implementation.

Comment: I like the suggestion where you check if the value is an Array. You say its a gross hack. Where would using this cause trouble?

Comment: @FlyingFoX It's a "gross hack" insofar as it's not idiomatic, not self-documenting, and not generally applicable (in the case where someone might want to pass an array as the first parameter).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
def strategy=(strategy, direction = :forward)
  @strategy = strategy
  @strategy.direction = direction
end
```

When you set

```
h.strategy = :mystrategy, :backward
```

you are actually overriding the original `@strategy` instance. After that call, `@strategy` is an instance of `Symbol`, not `MyArray`.

What do you want to do? Replace the object or update it?

Comment: Oh sry seems like I messed up the method. It should be `@strategy << strategy`.

Comment: Oh; so a strategy does not have a direction, but rather you have a list of strategies and a current direction?