# What are the restrictions for method names in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example, I found the method name `bundler?` in the following snippet, and don't know whether the `?` character is a specialized keyword or just part of the method name.

```
# This is a predicate useful for the doc:guides task of applications.
def bundler?
  # Note that rake sets the cwd to the one that contains the Rakefile
  # being executed.
  File.exists?('Gemfile')
end
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Method names in Ruby may contain upper-case and lower-case letters, numbers, underscores `_` and the punctation signs `!`, `?`, `=`.

A method name can't begin with a number, and the characters `!`, `?` and `=` can only appear at the end.

Non-ASCII characters can be used in a method name, but this can lead to very confusing situations and should not be common practice.

It's good practice, while not mandatory, to start the method name with a lower-case character, because names that start with capital letters are constants in Ruby. It's still possible to use a constant name for a method, but you won't be able to invoke it without parentheses, because the interpeter will look-up for the name as a constant:

```
def Capital
    nil
end

Capital    # NameError: uninitialized constant Capital
Capital()  # => nil
```

Some very widely and consistently used *conventions* when defining method names are:

1. Method names are full down-case, with underscores `_` as separators for words into the name (e.g. `Math::sqrt`, `Array#each_index`, ...).
2. *Predicates* have a question mark `?` as last character (e.g. `Array#empty?`, `Hash#has_key?`, ...). While predicates usually return boolean values, this is not always the case: these methods just need to return `nil` or `false` if the predicate evaluates to false, any other value otherwise (e.g. `File::size?` returns `nil` if the file does not exist, the size of the file as an `Integer` otherwise).
3. Methods that modify the state of the object on which they are invoked, or that have an unusual behavior have an exclamation mark `!` as last character; this methods are sometimes called *mutators* because they usually are destructive or in-place versions of other methods (e.g. `Array#sort!`, `Array#slice!`, ...).
4. *Setters* have an equal sign `=` as last character (e.g. `Array#[]=`, ...); the Ruby interpeter offers *syntactic sugar* for invokation of setter methods:

   ```
   a = [4, 5, 6]
   a[0] = 3    # Shorthand for a.[]=(0, 3)
   ```

Ruby also allows you to define operators using the operator symbol as the method name:

```
╔═══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Operators (by precedence) ║                 Operations                  ║ Arity ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ ! ~ +                     ║ Boolean NOT, bitwise complement, unary plus ║     1 ║
║                           ║ (define with method name +@, Ruby 1.9+)     ║       ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ **                        ║ Exponentiation                              ║     2 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ -                         ║ Unary minus (define with method name -@)    ║     1 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ * / %                     ║ Multiplication, division, modulo            ║     2 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ + -                       ║ Addition, subtraction                       ║     2 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ << >>                     ║ Bitwise shift                               ║     2 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ &                         ║ Bitwise AND                                 ║     2 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ | ^                       ║ Bitwise OR, Bitwise XOR                     ║     2 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ < <= => >                 ║ Ordering                                    ║     2 ║
║                           ║                                             ║       ║
║ == === != =~ !~ <=>       ║ Equality, pattern matching, comparison      ║     2 ║
╚═══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Unary operator methods are passed no arguments; binary operator methods are passed an argument, and operate on it and on `self`.

It's important to adhere strictly to the arity of the operators; while it is possible to define operator methods with a different arity (e.g. a `+` method that takes two arguments), Ruby would not allow you to call the method with operator syntax (it would however work with dot syntax).

It's good practice to adhere to the original semantics of the operators as much as possible: it should be intuitive to someone who knows the original meaning of the operator how it works with user defined classes.

The language also offers syntactic sugar for the special, *non-operator* ,`[]` method that is normally used for accessing array and hash values. The `[]` method can be defined with arbitrary arity.

For every binary operator in the table, except ordering, equality, comparison and pattern matching, Ruby also offers shorthand for abbreviated assignment (e.g. `x += y` expands to `x = x + y`); you can't define them as methods, but you can alter their behavior defining the operators on which they're based.

None of these characters can be used inside normal method names (e.g. `do&print` or `start-up` are not valid method names).

Comment: Great answer! As a little note: It is customary for predicate methods (with a `?`) to return falsey (`nil` or `false`) or truethy (everything else) values, not necessary `true` and `false`. The return value is intended to be used in `if` statements where it behaves like if it were `true`and `false` but the actual return value is often not part of the intended method interface, just it's truethy or falsey property.

Comment: There's also some characters that can only be used as the entire method name, i.e. you can define methods called - + * ** / (if you're overloading those operators) but not a method called foo+bar

Comment: I thought they were out of the scope of the question, but I added them for completeness.

Comment: I'm also having problems defining the method `+=` in a class. You can define `+` just fine, but not with the setter as you imply. I don't really know why and I'm not sure if it's a bug.

Comment: You can't define the abbreviated assignment operators directly, but if you define the associated operator (e.g. `+`) it will be automatically used when you use `+=` (check the second to last paragraph in the answer).

Comment: This is perhaps implied in the earlier description, but not quite explicitly enough: method names ending in `=` (setters) require to be "completed" by an expression, to be valid for the parser. So methods whose names end in `=` cannot be called with multiple arguments, using the paren-comma syntax. See a more detailed explanation in the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380796/creating-a-setter-method-that-takes-extra-arguments-in-ruby

Comment: @sameers Thank you for your suggestion; while I'm not sure this level of insight on parsing is appropriate for the scope of the question, I can see that my explanation of "setters" isn't perfectly clear, and I'll make sure to edit it accordingly.

Comment: @AlbertoMoriconi - thanks. The point that tripped me up (I was teaching Ruby when this happened) was I'd assumed the parser behavior reflects the actual semantics, which in this case it doesn't. Even though the "setter" is a method (you can `send` it to its containing object), the existence of the `=` at the end restricts the valid succeeding token sequences. The scope of the original question is a bit vague but (like me) others might show up here because they ran into the same issue.

Comment: Can you add an explanation for why someone would choose to name a method with a capital first letter like def Cats; end?

Comment: @mbigras, you can see some examples of such methods in the Ruby core; e.g., [Kernel#Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) is used to convert a value to an array. So, the inferred idiomatic use-case is for conversion methods. Another example can be found in the Ruby Std-Lib, [Object#CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-CSV).

Comment: Source: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names

Answer (score 9):

What others say is true for the built-in syntax, however there seems to be no back-end restrictions on what can be used if you use methods like `define_method` + `send`:

```
define_method(:'$% ^&') { 0 }
define_method(:'你好') { 1 }

send(:'$% ^&') == 0 or raise
send(:'你好') == 1 or raise
```

This fact can be useful: for example Rails' [ActiveSupport::Testing::Declarative.test](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Declarative.html#method-i-test) method uses it so as not to do complex conversions on:

```
test 'Some Controller#Method' do
```

to a saner name, which might conflict with another test named:

```
test 'Some Controller_Method' do
```

This is mentioned on the [Testing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#unit-testing-your-models).

Curiosity: a similar thing happens in Java, where the bytecode method name gives way more choice than the Java language: [Why does the JVM allow us to name a function starting with a digit in bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791204/why-does-the-jvm-allow-us-to-name-a-function-starting-with-a-digit-in-bytecode)

Answer (score 4):

Method names can end in `!`, `?` or `=`. Underscores are allowed as well. Besides that there are several methods that look like operators (e.g. `+`, `*`, `>>`, `[]`) that you can define for your own classes.

Answer (score 2):

To add one thing: you can also tell an object to run a method with *no name at all* and it will try to invoke a method named `call`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Foo

=begin
  def call(*args)
    puts "received call with #{args.join(' ')}"
  end
=end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    puts "received method_missing on `#{m}(#{args.join(', ')})`"
  end

end

f = Foo.new
f.('hi')             # Not a syntax error! method_missing with m of :call
f.send :'', 'hmm'    # method_missing with m set to :''
f.send nil, 'bye'    # raises an error
```

There is not actually any method named `call` defined on `Object`, but there is one on the `Method` and `Proc` classes.

In some languages `()` is an operator for function invocation, and that seems pretty similar to what's happening here.

This is used e.g. in Rails' JBuilder:

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

It is documented on page 196 of the O'Reilly Ruby book:

> Ruby 1.9 offers an additional way to invoke a `Proc` object; as an alternative to square brackets, you can use parentheses prefixed with a period:
>
> ```
> z = f.(x,y)
> ```
>
> `.()` looks like a method invocation missing the method name. This is not an operator that can be defined, but rather is syntactic-sugar that invokes the `call` method. It can be used with any object that defines a `call` method and is not limited to `Proc` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The characters allowed are: `a-Z,`, `0-9` as long as not at the beginning, `_`, and `?` (for boolean functions) and `!` (for destructive functions) and `=` (for setters).