# How does the ruby interpreter tell when you're calling a method on an integer or when you're setting a float?

Tags: ruby

I had a look through the `0.methods` output in `irb` and couldn't see what path the ruby interpreter would take when it was passed `0.15` as opposed to `0.to_s`

I've tried reading up on how ruby determines the difference between a floating point number being defined and a method being called on an integer but I haven't come to any conclusions.

The best guess I have is that because Ruby doesn't allow for a digit to lead a method name, it simply checks whether the character following the `.` is numeric or alphabetical.

I don't like guessing though, assumptions can lead to misunderstandings. Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking how Ruby decides that `0.15` is a `Float` literal rather than a call of method `15` on `Fixnum` literal `0`? I don't see why it should matter. It seems obvious that `15` isn't a method, but the only way to know for sure is to examine the Ruby compiler. It is much the same question as why `0` on its own isn't a method call. It puzzles me how you think looking at the list returned by `0.methods` would help.

Comment: Yep, that's what I want to know. It doesn't matter for any programming purpose or exercise, but I want to understand if there's something there that might be helpful down the track. I'm just curious, that's all, and I certainly hope curiousity will be encouraged by other programmers who know better than I, not just pushed aside by those who don't know the answer. I'm quite certain that if I tried to understand the ruby compiler that I'd get lost. I've not written a lexer or parser myself, so trying to understand one which is undoubtedly quite complex is above me for now.

Comment: I looked at `0.methods` because from a layman's point of view, it seems like the place to look when trying to work out what Ruby would do when a `.` follows a literal. I didn't know what I was hoping to find, but I didn't find anything meaningful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How well can you read Yacc files? (Rhetorical question)

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L7380 I believe this is where the Ruby parser handles floating point tokenisation.

Disclaimer: parse.y hurts my head.

Comment: Excellent spotting... I'm going to have to go over that a few times to get it properly.

Answer (score 0):

As [Methods in Ruby cannot begin with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542354/what-are-the-restrictions-for-method-names-in-ruby), it's pretty easy to determine that `6.foo` is a Method call and `6.12` is a `Float`.

You can distinguish both of them by pretty simple regular grammar specs, which is all what a Lexer needs to tokenize the source code.

Comment: That seems quite reasonable. Thanks for the additional link there, that helped clear it up nicely, and also gave me a bit more information about the restrictions and flexibility of method names in Ruby.

Comment: This is nothing but a restatement of the question: *“because Ruby doesn't allow for a digit to lead a method name, it simply checks whether the character following the `.` is numeric or alphabetical“* It is (probably perfectly correct) speculation, and not a definitive description of *how* Ruby determines the difference between a float and a method call. No one can provide that without checking the Ruby source.

Comment: No, Borodin. It is an expansion on what I thought may be the case, with both a link to a useful answer elsewhere and someone who knows more about lexer's than I adding weight to my assumption.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know for sure, but I think it is safe to assume that the two are distinguished by method names being unable to start with a number.

I don't see that it's an especially interesting or useful thing to know, and I think your curiosity is best directed elsewhere.