# What is the "other" object and how does it work?

Tags: ruby

I have seen `other` used often in class comparisons, such as

```
def ==(other)
  ...
end
```

or

```
def eql?(other)
  self == other
end
```

but I still have found no explanation of what it actually is. What's going on here?

And perhaps this is for another question, but what does starting a method with `==` imply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ruby, operators are in fact method calls. If you have two variables `a` and `b` and want to check their equality, you generally write `a == b`, but you could write `a.==(b)`. The last syntax shows what happens during an equality check : ruby calls `a`'s method `==` and passes it `b` as an argument.

You can implement custom equality check in your classes by defining the `==` and/or the `eql?` methods. In your example, `other` is simply the name of the argument it receives.

```
class Person
     attr_accessor :name

    def initialize name
        @name = name
    end
end

a = Person.new("John")
b = Person.new("John")
a == b # --> false

class Person
    def == other
        name == other.name
    end
end
a == b # --> true
```

For your second question, the only methods starting with `==` you're allowed to implement are `==` and `===`. Check here for the full list of restrictions on method names in ruby: [What are the restrictions for method names in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542354/what-are-the-restrictions-for-method-names-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

`other` is a parameter to this method, the object, that is being passed.

For example:

```
class A
  def ==(other)
    :lala == other
  end
end

obj = A.new
obj.==(:foo) # full syntax, just like any other method
# but there's also a shorthand for operators:
obj == :foo  # => false
obj == :lala # => true
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. I had been thinking that `other` must be a predefined object like `self` but in fact it's just a commonly-used parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`other` is the parameter for `==` and it represents **the object you are comparing** with.

Example

```
x == y
```

The `==` method (yes, its just a method!), on your `x` object, gets called with `y` as a parameter.

Welcome to Ruby, you'll love it after a while :)

Comment: I need to get a tattoo that reminds me that operators are methods, too! This keeps slipping my mind so your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped. Put that tattoo anywhere but on your back ;)

Answer (score 0):

`other`, in this case, is the object you're comparing to, so this:

```
class SomeClass
  def ==(other)
    self == other
  end
end
```

means:

```
SomeClass.new == nil # here "other" is nil, this returns false
```

Basically `def ==(other)` is the implementation of the `==` operator, for cases where you do *something specific* in your class regarding comparison using `==`.

Answer (score 0):

For numbers you can get the sum of 2 numbers using:

```
a= x + y
```

in Ruby everything is object, Right! so `x` and `y` are objects and for Number(Object) `x` it has a defined method `+` which accept 1 paramter which is `y`

same for what you are trying to understand, what if you have 2 classes and you want to check if they are equal or not and its your defined class and you want to specify how the are equal for example if their `name` attribute is equal then you can say:

```
class Student
  def ==(other)
   self.name == other.name
  end  
end

fi = Student.new(name: 'Mark')
sec = Student.new(name: 'Hany')
if (fi == sec)
  # do something here
```