# Can I override `.<digit>` to point at an index for an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

`.<digit>` means to interpret the number as a float instead of an integer.

Can I override `.<digit>` to let it point the index in an array so that the following will work?

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c.0 # => 1
c.3 # => 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A method name can't begin with a number in Ruby. More about Ruby method names restrictions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542354/what-are-the-restrictions-for-method-names-in-ruby).

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. That is part of the literal expression for floats. It is not a method call. It is not done at Ruby syntax level.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already told, it is not possible to override the number as method, but you can use parenthesis for an empty method.

```
class Array
  def method_missing(m ,*args, &block)
    # m will be 'call'
    self[args[0]] if args[0].is_a?(Fixnum)
  end
end


irb(main):009:0> [1,2,3,4,5].(0)
=> 1
irb(main):010:0> [1,2,3,4,5].(2)
=> 3
```

Comment: You can do it better like: `class Array; alias call []; end`.