# How to define unnamed method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was reading on cells gem when I suddenly got curious on its implementation of unnamed method in its [documentation](https://github.com/apotonick/cells#rendering-cells).

Particularly the code below:

`CommentCell.(@comment).()`

and

`cell(:comment, @song).(:index)`

where it uses `.(arguments)` without a method name.

I am certain the answer is just somewhere in the source code itself. But briefly looking at [`Cell::ViewModel`](https://github.com/apotonick/cells/blob/master/lib/cell/view_model.rb) doesn't immediately help me, so I was just wondering first if anyone knows how to do this before I thoroughly inspect the source code, and hopefully satisfies my curiosity.

I can see some uses of this in the app that I will be making soon.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Can I override `.<digit>` to point at an index for an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37067744/can-i-override-digit-to-point-at-an-index-for-an-array/37067983#37067983)

Comment: @potashin Ohh?! It's actually a lambda? That's cool :) Thanks. I'll try it out. Would you like to put your comment as an answer instead?

Comment: @AlexN ok. Thanks. I'll check it out :)

Comment: @AlexN I tried it and it worked cool! :) Would you like to put your comment as an answer instead?

Comment: `CommentCell = ->(who) { -> { puts "hiya, #{who}" } }; CommentCell.("Bob").() #=> "hiya, Bob"; CommentCell["Bob"][] #=> "hiya, Bob"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.()` looks like a method invocation missing the method name. This is syntactic-sugar that invokes the `call` method. It can be used with any object that defines a call method and works with `Proc` or `lambda`.

```
class Test
  def call
    puts "test"
  end
end

t = Test.new
t.()
# => "test"
lambda {puts "test"}.()
Proc.new {puts "test"}.()
```

But there are other possible solutions to react on `.()`. You could override `method_missing` or set an alias.

```
class Test
  def test
    puts "test"
  end

  alias call test;
end

t = Test.new
t.()
# => "test"
```

Comment: To just safely handle only noname method name, does it need to be something like the following? `def method_missing(m, *args, &block); if m==''; DO_SOMETHING; end`

Comment: Tried your answer and it worked. I see... so it does not need to be `method_missing` and seems like `call` is a special or reserved method name. Thanks :)

Comment: No, `call` is not a special or reserved method name. It's a method just like any other. It's just that `foo.()` gets translated to `foo.call()` in exactly the same manner that `foo[bar, baz] = quux` gets translated to `foo.[]=(bar, baz, quux)` or `+foo` gets translated to `foo.+@()` or `not foo` gets translated to `foo.!()`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ohh i see. that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to figure out what method call a particular piece of syntax translates to, you can try that out yourself:

```
class << foo = BasicObject.new
  def method_missing(meth, *args)
    $>.puts "`foo.#{meth}(#{args.inspect[1...-1]})`"
  end

  BasicObject.instance_methods.each(&method(:undef_method))
end

print '`foo.(1, 2, 3)` gets translated to '
foo.(1, 2, 3)
# `foo.(1, 2, 3)` gets translated to `foo.call(1, 2, 3)`

print '`not foo` gets translated to '
not foo
# `not foo` gets translated to `foo.!()`

print '`+foo` gets translated to '
+foo
# `+foo` gets translated to `foo.+@()`

print '`~foo` gets translated to '
~foo
# `~foo` gets translated to `foo.~()`

print '`foo[1, 2, 3] = 4` gets translated to '
foo[1, 2, 3] = 4
`foo[1, 2, 3] = 4` gets translated to `foo.[]=(1, 2, 3, 4)`
```

And so on …

As you can see, `foo.(bar, baz)` gets translated to `foo.call(bar, baz)`.