# How can I achieve this result in ruby?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, interface, sequel

I was reading the Sequel's docs and I'm got curious about the technique used in the following code snippet:

```
class Post < Sequel::Model(:my_posts)
  (...)
end
```

The `Sequel::Model(:my_posts)` sets the database table for the model. I'm curious specifically about the parenthesis in `Model(:my_posts)`. I like this interface, but how can I achieve that? It's a bit weird... Seems like the `Model` can be called as a method... Which is this technique? Can somebody give me an example?

Comment: This is just calling the method named `Model` on the object referenced by the constant `Sequel`, passing the `Symbol` `:my_posts` as an argument. That method presumably returns an instance of the `Class` class, otherwise you will get a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you use `::` with module or class, ruby will try to find expression after `::` in constants.

```
Example::First => as constant
Example::First() => as method
```

Run this code:

```
module Example
  class << self
    def First(a)
      puts a
    end
  end

  module First
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
Example::First(1) # => prints 1
```

When you use `class << self` you open self's class so that methods can be redefined for the current self object (which inside a class or module body is the class or module itself). Read good [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby) on SO.

> It's good practice, while not mandatory, to start the method name with
>   a lower-case character, because names that start with capital letters
>   are constants in Ruby. It's still possible to use a constant name for
>   a method, but you won't be able to invoke it without parentheses,
>   because the interpeter will look-up for the name as a constant

From [What are the restrictions for method names in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542354/what-are-the-restrictions-for-method-names-in-ruby)

Comment: Sequel defined a method `def_model`  (see [here](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/ClassMethods.html#method-i-def_Model)) to define a Model method on any given module