# Ruby: usage of ? in if condition

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what is the difference of using "?" inside if condition?

```
if object.property
```

or

```
if object.property?
```

I found the usage of both of them in a method, without understanding the difference

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

`?` can be part of the function name. It is not a special operator if it comes at the end of a method name. Also `!` can be part of the method name too. So what that line is doing is calling both `object.property` and `object.property?` methods.

[What are the restrictions for method names in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542354/what-are-the-restrictions-for-method-names-in-ruby)

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby, `foo.bar` is the syntax for a *message send*. It will first evaluate the expression `foo` (which is either dereferencing a local variable or a receiverless message send to the implicit receiver `self`) and then send the message `bar` to the resulting object.

Once you know what message send in Ruby looks like, it is easy to see what `object.property?` does: It will first evaluate the expression `object` (which is either dereferencing a local variable or a receiverless message send to the implicit receiver `self`) and then send the message `property?` to the resulting object.

So, what is the difference between the two? Well, the first one sends the message `property` and the second one sends the message `property?`. This is no different than if the first one had been `object.foo` and the second one had been `object.bar`.

Method names ending in `?` are typically used for *predicate* methods, i.e. for methods that ask a "Yes/No" question. A good example is [`Numeric#zero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-zero-3F).