# Assigning multiple values to setter at once: self.x = (y, z) results in a syntax error

Tags: ruby, syntax, setter, getter-setter

I'm trying to define a class method using two arguments - title and author. When I try to pass my arguments I'm getting an argument error

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
>   book.set_title_and_author= ("Ender's Game", "Orson Scott Card")

```
class Book

  def set_title_and_author= (title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end

  def description
    "#{@title}was written by #{@author}"
  end

end

book = Book.new

book.set_title_and_author= ("Ender's Game", "Orson Scott Card)

p book.description
```

Am I not allowed to pass more than one argument in my setter method or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380796/creating-a-setter-method-that-takes-extra-arguments-in-ruby

Comment: Parenthesis do *not* create "tuples" in Ruby. Trying to use them as such will result in a syntax error, used with a setter or not. Also, being a class method (which it is not) vs. an instance method/setter (which it is) is irrelevant.

Comment: Nitpick on your question title, by the way. This isn't a class method, it's an *instance* method. The term "class method" is reserved for methods like `Book.new` that are called on the class itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indeed can't pass more than one argument to a method that ends in `=`. A setter method doesn't need to end in `=`, though, naturally: you can just do `set_title_and_author(title, author)`.

Another alternative would be to have the method take an array:

```
def set_title_and_author= (title_and_author)
    @title, @author = title_and_author
end

#...

book.set_title_and_author= ["Ender's Game", "Orson Scott Card"]
```

If you do the latter, stylistically I'd recommend removing the `set` and just calling the method `title_and_author=`. `set` is redundant with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Book
  def set_title_and_author(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end

  def description
    "#{@title}was written by #{@author}"
  end
end

book = Book.new
book.set_title_and_author("Ender's Game", "Orson Scott Card")
p book.description
```

but more clear approach will be

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author

  def description
    "#{@title}was written by #{@author}"
  end
end

book = Book.new
book.title = "Ender's Game"
book.author = "Orson Scott Card"
p book.description
```

And finally using constructor for setting attributes (and avoiding unnecessary mutability) is much better

```
book = Book.new("Ender's Game", "Orson Scott Card")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `=` sign is unnecessary. Do following:

```
class Book
  def set_title_and_author(title, author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end

  def description
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}"
  end
end
book = Book.new
book.set_title_and_author("Ender's Game","Orson Scott Card")
p book.description
```

This worked for me.